# Output from SQL query needs to be in the same order as the input

Tags: sql, oracle

I've taken a look through some of the other answers on the site for this one, but none seem to match my problem (or at least don't look like it to my eyes!).

I'm adjusting an Excel macro, it takes a list of customer references and runs a SQL Query via Microsoft ODBC on the Oracle database.  The query itself works fine and returns the correct results.  However the user wants the results to be in the same order as the original list of customer references.

So for example a list of 2001145, 2001101, 2200110 should return the results in that order instead of 2001101, 2001145, 2200110.

I'm looking for a way to do this in the SQL command, is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

---

Here is the code to do the query.  I don't need to sort the input, I need the output in the same (unsorted) order as the input.

```
Sql = " select b.column Customer, (b.CURR_BAL + b.CURR_BAL_V) Balance"
Sql = Sql & " from table b"
Sql = Sql & " WHERE b.column = 5"
Sql = Sql & " and b.column in (" & custRefList & ")"

'Runs the SQL Query, result applied to the destination
'Don't need to worry about any other settings exceot the UID,PRD and SERVER depending on system (same as toad)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=*****;PWD=*****;SERVER=*****;" _
        , Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandText = (Sql)
        .Name = "Query from *****"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: Show the ODBC VB instruction and the Oracle query please.

Comment: Generally you do no have such thing as ordered user input, you have [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) (which is unordered), so basically you cannot do what you need. But here can be tricks sometimes, they all will degrade performance. Maybe the easiest solution is to sort results on excel side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate this query to your vb and it should be fine:

```
SELECT 
    t.cli Customer, 
    (b.CURR_BAL + b.CURR_BAL_V) Balance
FROM table b
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                level,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(custRefList, '[^ |,]+', 1, level) cli
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(custRefList, '[^ |,]+')
        ) t ON b.column = t.cli
WHERE b.column = 5
ORDER BY t.level
```